# Django app has multiple database and multiple user

Tags: django

I have written one Django cloud based app. This app will have multiple user and for them multiple database, so that their data should be separate and they can save only to same database.

1) How can we implement it

2) How to automatically one user from login page to assign the database to write on it.

Comment: This is way too broad of a question. There likely dozens of ways to accomplish this, with several of those ways being "good".

Comment: Without seeing your data how can we tell? You might have very few stop words so the result isn't really affected. Voting to close, can't be sure what, if any, the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete answer, since you do not give a lot of detail. But here are a couple ots that f hinDjango supports custom database router implementations. A database router is a class that helps django decide which database to use for a particular model. Unfortunately I don't think this mechanism is granular enough for your needs. You can also specify the database to use in your code by using `using(name)` queryset method and `save(using=name)` form of `save()` method for instances. Of course this also means that some features of Django are going to be unvailable to you, since you cannot always expect to have a user. Look at the docs here for more info

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/